# Cannot create KDS Root Key - "Request is not supported"

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 domain controller (sole DC and first computer in the domain) all freshly built and all up to date. I'm trying to create a group Managed Service Account (gmsa) which requires a KDS Root Key first. I launch the Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell using Run as Administrator and issue the following:

```
Add-KDSRootKey -EffectiveTime ((get-date).addhours(-11))
```

I get an error "The request is not supported".

[image]

**If I change it to -EffectiveImmediately, I get the same error.**

The KDS cmdlets are installed

[image] and I can use them to list keys (empty) and view configuration - I just can't seem to add a KDS root key. I've struggled with this for two days now - any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try right click on the powershell icon and run as administrator and rerun the command.

Also be attentive to privileges. Creating a KDS Root Key requires **Domain Administrator** (in the root top-level domain) or **Enterprise Administrator** privileges.

Answer (score 2):

FYI for anyone finding this question in the future. I was able to resolve it like this:

- (1) Log on to another non-DC in the domain
- (2) Log on as a domain
  admin
- (3) Install/add the RSAT tools (the AD ones in particular)
- (4) Launch the PowerShell AD tool
- (5) Run the Add-KDSRootKey from the new machine.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

since KDS Root Key is unique in entire Forest. Run powershell module as enterprise admin privileges will server the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it should work -> Add-KdsRootKey –EffectiveTime ((get-date).addhours(-10))

This is because 10 hours is the default time to wait for it to be available. -11 exceeds that.